# linux/Bash pull out variables from curl output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, centos

There is this script for testing the internet speed directly from the command line:

`curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py | python -`

```
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from XXXX (X.X.X.5)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by XXXX (XX) [0.54 km]: 3.513 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 191.68 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed................................................................................................
Upload: 154.36 Mbit/s
```

I know I can get either the Download or Upload line using `| grep Download/Upload`

But how can I cast both Download and Upload into a variables?

Comment: Capture the result, and you can search through it more than once.

Comment: Ask the script for a machine processable format. I see it has a `--csv` option.

Comment: BTW, you're putting a lot of trust into sivel not to let their github credentials be leaked, in github not to have a security breach, etc. Much safer to cache `speedtest.py` locally than to download a new version every time you run it, which (if you're cronning that invocation) means that any transient exploit will hit you. (If said maintainer GPG-signs their release tags, then you can verify that a git commit really came from them, subject to an appropriate level of confidence around private key storage).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How would I even curl `speedtest.py` locally? If not curl, what can I use to run it?

Comment: `result=$(python /path/to/speedtest.py)`. `curl` is a download tool. You don't need it at all if the script is already downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# save your value *once*
result=$(curl ...)

# ...then you can search through it multiple times.
if [[ $result =~ 'Download: '([[:digit:].]+)' Mbit' ]]; then 
    download_speed=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
if [[ $result =~ 'Upload: '([[:digit:].]+)' Mbit' ]]; then 
    upload_speed=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi

echo "Test results: Download speed ${download_speed:-unknown}"
echo "              Upload speed ${upload_speed:-unknown}"
```

Answer (score 1):

In one shot:

```
mapfile -t speeds < <(
    curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py | 
    python - | 
    grep -oP '(Up|Down)load: \K[\d.]+'
)
echo "Down: ${speeds[0]}"
echo "Up: ${speeds[1]}"
```